# IOS Upload Images To AWS 3 Generate Random Unique Key Names

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I am currently using Amazon S3 to upload images from an IOS app with Cognito Identities and a custom back-end server.

When uploading the image, a key needs to be set for the image URL

```
_uploadRequest.key = @"filename.jpg";
```

The final image URL will be:

```
http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname/filename.jpg
```

Is there a good way to generate unique random strings in IOS in order to have unique filenames or would it be to generate them server side (Rails back-end) ?

Comment: Have you considered an md5 or sha hash of the image data?  That gives you "random" and also avoids duplicate content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can 
1. Append current date and time to filename(but it may fail if you create some filename at once)

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd he:mm:ss"
let key1 = "filename_" + dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate()) + ".jpg"
```

2. Use NSUUID and getting string representation from it

```
let key2 = "filename_" + NSUUID().UUIDString + ".jpg"
```

3. And other ways as well

Answer (score 0):

file name should be generated from code end only and for that you can make any specific format as like the live DateandTime to string for specific timed image. which may help.